# Prevent jQuery from traversing parts of document

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on a website with heavy use of Ajax request that build up a tab based structure in the DOM. My concern is that the DOM will accumulate so many tabs and elements that JQuery selectors will eventually perform poorly.

Is there a way to maintain a large DOM, but offer JQuery a "hint" to exclude certain sections. For example I would like to maintain the elements in the DOM, but only have my JQuery selectors apply to the active tab.

I was hoping there would be some sort of "ignore" tag that I could dynamically apply to inactive sections

Perhaps it's an alternative to store the inactive tab elements in the data dictionary, and bring them in and out of the DOM as they come into focus.

Comment: Can you post some code? It depends really on what you're trying to do

Comment: It's more a conceptual question. I am looking for an approach to tag DOM content to be ignored by JQuery

Comment: The answer to what you're asking is basicly - no ! On the other hand if it's well structured with unique identifiers, javascript can handle a pretty big DOM before it starts becoming a problem, and my experience is that browser rendering will be a problem long before that.

Comment: Yes I am not seing the problem yet, but have some concern because some of the selectors are very broad (class based etc). The answer using context might be a solution. I could potentially set the context to the active tab upon selecting a tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `context` method:

*The DOM node context originally passed to jQuery(); if none was passed then context will likely be the document.*

http://api.jquery.com/context/

Comment: This is a potential solution. I have to explore it some more

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a selector which tells jquery what you want.  For example, give each tab an `id`.  Then if you want to get all `a` tags in the `news`tab:

```
$("#news a")
```

jQuery will then know only to look in `#news`.

`id` queries in general are very efficient as only one element can have a given `id`.

Comment: No this isn't always an option since some of the selectors are reusable across sections and I don't have the luxury of providing granular selectors like that

Comment: If you don't control the code then you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, the way you use your selectors depends on the your code. But if you end up with a huge selector list you can always `filter()` the collection with any rule.

```
$elements.filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent('.foo').length; // Only elements with parent `.foo`
});
```

Comment: The concern is more the search time I will be dealing with due to the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

On your selectors you can pass a context as second parameter to tell jquery what part of your document to look on, let's say: `var selectedItem = $('#listItem' + i, $('.myList'));` this reduces the amount of nodes to look for.
Reference: http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip9

Comment: I am looking for a solution that doesn't deal with providing granular selectors since it's not always an option for some of the shared code

Comment: Well, the reference i posted could help you find what you're looking for